# Clean Mavericks install after doing a normal upgrade, can I do it using the recovery partition?

Tags: reinstall, osx-mavericks

I have upgraded my MacBook Pro to OS X Mavericks, but I'm seeing some problems. I think it is related to a botched fiddling with TinkerTool earlier (my fault) and so I want to do a clean installation of OS X.

I've found numerous webpages telling me how to create a bootable USD Disk and copying the required files onto that disk, this question is not about that.

I tried booting the MBP while holding down the Option key and I got two disks:

- System Disk
- **Recovery-10.9**

Clearly Mavericks has done something to the recovery disk.

Does the recovery disk contain a fully installable copy of Mavericks, or only repair and diagnostics tools, meaning, do I really need to make that external USB disk now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just containing tools to recover your partition, but also a downloader aka "Internet Recovery" which will always download you an image so you can reinstall your system (if your MacBook is recent enough).
You don't have to create an external USB disk as long you have a working internet connection.

For more information see [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718?viewlocale=en_US) document provided by Apple.

Comment: Thanks, then I guess I'll make a backup of the few data folders I have and try the reinstall option.